# How does Mailchimp manages to move box below antoher one when window size changes size (css3/media queries)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, media-queries

I'm not a huge expert on CSS3 and i wonder how mailchimp manages to get on their [sign in page](https://login.mailchimp.com/), to put the "stay logged in" box go under the login box and both extend to a 100% width (rather than 50% for each when there is a wider screen size).

As I am not an expert, I wonder if they do it by pure standard CSS (something easy) or if they use media queries (i heard about it). 
If it's media queries, then I'll try to dig into that!

Here are the 2 pictures:

- for a quite large screen, eahc button share 50% width on a same horizontal line

[image]

- for smaller screens, each button spread on the whole width (100% width) and spans over 2 lines

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its using media queries

Check the following links to get more information and get started about it

http://mediaqueri.es/

http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/